# notepad++ regex to replace spaces between specific tags

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have this:

```
<div>Accomack (County)</div>
<span>Prince Georges (County)</span>
<div>Richmond (Ind. City)</div>
```

I'd like to replace spaces with dashes only between "div" tags.
When I search for

```html
<div>.*?(\s).*?</div>
```

Notepad++ selects whole thing including "div" tags. 
How to select only spaces between "div" tags?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well the whole div matches the search string.  Search for ``<div>(.*)(\s)(.*)</div>`` replace with `<div>\1-\3</div>` and repeat until there are no more matches.

Comment: Actually, you need `(?:\G(?!^)|<div\b[^<]*?>)(?:(?!</?div\b[^<]*?>).)*?\K\s` and replace with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Find what: `(<div.*) (\(.*)`
Replace with: `$1-$2`
However there are some sites to explain the Regex.
But I try to explain it with pictures to show that what I have captured with my regex.
Note! Making photo explanation take me sometime hours to prepare it, I hope it will be helpful to new users...regards

[image]

Comment: I only can try to prepare photo explanation, which takes some times to prepare

Comment: You don't replace all spaces, `<span>Prince Georges (County)</span>` is not modified but it shoud.

Comment: You must to read it carefully, the asker didn't want it so, otherwise it is easiest of all, search ` spacè - Replace with `-`

Comment: (Re)read the question. They want to replace spaces inside `<div` tags, you don't replace spaces in the second line. Where have you seen that is not wanted? And, inside the second `div` you don't replace the space between `Ind.` and `City`

Comment: OK let it for now to be like this,  if otherwise the asker really meant as you pointed to, then I will prepare my second answer, ,, and this seems to be impossible otherwise would be answered already....